# initrd.lz is corrupted error occured while installing 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wubi

C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz is corrupted. Error pop-up comes up every time i am trying to install ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386 using wubi. error comes when the installation process is almost completed. can anyone suggest a solution for this problem. Its occurring regularly.

```
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running copy_installation_files...
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\HP_OWN~1.YOU\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl59.tmp\data\custom-installation -> C:\ubuntu\install\custom-installation
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\HP_OWN~1.YOU\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl59.tmp\winboot -> C:\ubuntu\winboot
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\DOCUME~1\HP_OWN~1.YOU\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl59.tmp\data\images\Ubuntu.ico -> C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Trying to use pre-specified ISO X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: New task is_valid_iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running is_valid_iso...
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
03-19 18:01 INFO   Distro: Found a valid iso for Ubuntu: X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished is_valid_iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running check_iso...
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
03-19 18:01 INFO   Distro: Found a valid iso for Ubuntu: X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Using distro Ubuntu i386 instead of Ubuntu amd64
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_metalink
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_metalink...
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
03-19 18:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink err=[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (7, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/oneiric-desktop-i386.metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
03-19 18:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file2 http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/oneiric-desktop-i386.metalink err=[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (7, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
03-19 18:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: ERROR: the metalink file is not available, cannot check the md5 for X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso, ignoring
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Copying X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso > C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished copy_file
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished get_iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Extracting files from ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting md5sum.txt from C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting casper\vmlinuz from C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting casper\initrd.lz from C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking kernel, initrd and md5sums
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   checking C:\ubuntu\install\boot\vmlinuz
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   C:\ubuntu\install\boot\vmlinuz md5 = fde150f5c6fd2de66ed7876efbfcc4c7 == fde150f5c6fd2de66ed7876efbfcc4c7
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   checking C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz md5 = 8900200c764438c1b124dff5ae92c763 != d6baee1e11f1d6de6eba6bd43dbde352
03-19 18:01 ERROR  TaskList: File C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz is corrupted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 623, in extract_kernel
Exception: File C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz is corrupted
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
03-19 18:01 ERROR  root: File C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz is corrupted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 623, in extract_kernel
Exception: File C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz is corrupted
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

Comment: Please open the wubi log file in the `%TEMP%` directory and search for the `initrd.lz` md5 fail, then edit your questions and copy and paste that and at least 15 lines above it.

Comment: This log might help you to find the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi checks the md5sum of the ISO when installing. In this case the ISO is on `X:\`:

```
03-19 18:01 INFO   Distro: Found a valid iso for Ubuntu: X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
```

So Wubi tries to download the metalink file that contains the md5sum so it can validate the ISO. But the download failed (not connected to the internet?), so it bypassed that step.

```
03-19 18:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.metalink err=[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (7, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
...
03-19 18:01 ERROR  CommonBackend: ERROR: the metalink file is not available, cannot check the md5 for X:\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso, ignoring
```

But it still checks vmlinuz and initrd.lz it extracts from the ISO using the md5sums written to the ISO. This is where it's failing.

```
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   checking C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz
03-19 18:01 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz md5 = 8900200c764438c1b124dff5ae92c763 != d6baee1e11f1d6de6eba6bd43dbde352
03-19 18:01 ERROR  TaskList: File C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz is corrupted
```

So, in summary, it looks like your CD/ISO is corrupt. Download a new one.

Comment: The installer Wubi runs completely this time and asked to reboot or not. I rebooted it and selected ubuntu at the startup. The installer starts again in ubuntu and suddenly an error occurs:    "The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk: [Error 5] input/output error. This is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or faulty hard disk."

Comment: Are you saying you tried again with the same ISO, but this time it didn't fail in Windows with the corrupt initrd? And then it failed when you rebooted to complete the install? Or did you use a new ISO?

Comment: Yes i tried with the same ISO, and it failed when I rebooted to complete the installation.

Comment: But then i again run Wubi and allowed it to download a new ISO and install it. This time it got completed without any error, asked for reboot and completes the installation.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 is now installed. Thanks to you @bcbc.

Comment: Did you run an md5 check on it?

Comment: Ok great (ignore my last comment). Glad you got it sorted out.